# Mi programa en C++ ignora las funciones que deberían detenerlo si las coloco por si solas

Tags: c++

Buen día, estoy aprendiendo a usar C++ y me encontré con este problema que como dice el titulo consiste en que al colocar una función que debería de frenar mi código (según tengo entendido) como lo es `getchar()` o `cin.get()` por si sola al final del mismo este simplemente la ignora y se termina a si mismo sin darme tiempo de ver la ultima parte lo cual me resulto especialmente extraño considerando que si se detiene al leer un cin.get() si comento el `cin>>n1` y descomento el `cin.get()` al comienzo de la función.

En resumen, a menos que coloque `getchar()` y `cin.get()` juntos al final de mi código este no se detiene como se supone debería, y por lo tanto deseaba saber si existe algún modo de solucionar esto sin tener que usar `<cstdio>` en conjunto con `<iostream>` como hice mas abajo y también si es posible una explicación de por que sucede esto. Estoy operando en Windows 8.1 y usando wxCev-C++ en caso de que eso afecte en algo.

De antemano deseo agradecerles a quienes se tomen el tiempo de leer este post.

```
//Codigo de ejemplo:

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main (){
    //cin.get();
    float n1 , iva = 0.21;
    cout << "ingrese un numero"; cin>>n1;
    float n2 = n1 + n1*iva;
    cout << "este es su numero despues del iva: " << n2;
    
    cin.get();
    getchar();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninguna de esas funciones detiene la ejecución. Consultemos la documentación:

- [`std::basic_istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get): Lee un caracter y lo devuelve si está disponible. En caso contrario devuelve `Traits::eof()` y establece `failtbit` y `eofbit`.
- [`std::getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar): Devuelve un caracter o `EOF` en caso de fallo.

Cualquiera de las dos funciones leerá un carácter del búfer de entrada, si no hay nada que leer devolverán *End of File*.

Comment: entonces segun lo que ley .get() deberia agarra un char . getchar() lee el siguiente caracter que se le presente asique supongo que al ponerlos juntos get char se pausa asta obtener un valor del cin.get(), supongo. perdone es que soy lento en general pero entonces la unica pregunta que me quedaria es ¿No existe otra forma de hacer que mi programa se detenga al final sin tener que importar otra libreria ademas de <iostream>?

Comment: Probablemente no valla a leer esto pero solo le quería agradecer por su tiempo leeré la documentación cuando no sepa que hace una función en vez de solo hacer caso a un foro del 2007 de ahora en adelante muchas gracias. por cierto arregle el problema de no querer importar demaciadas librerias a mi codigo simplemente cambiandome a una vercion mas nueva de dev-c++ al final.

Comment: @Krumplem_1 Si quieres que la consola se detenga necesitas usar herramientas del sistema operativo, no de [tag:C++] ya que la consola no depende del lenguaje si no del sistema operativo.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por su tiempo.